# Add(index, element) method

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a method add(int index, E element) that is supposed to insert the specified element at the specified index in a list and shift the element currently at that position and any subsequent elements to the right. Does anyone know why my method does not work when my code is:

```
        newNode.setNext(temp.getNext());
        newNode.setPrev(temp);
        newNode.getNext().setPrev(newNode);
        temp.setNext(newNode);
```

at the end of the method but works when I have only

```
        newNode.setNext(temp.getNext());
        temp.setNext(newNode);
```

My code:

```
public class DoubleLinkedList<E> implements IDoubleLinkedList<E> {

DLLNode head;
DLLNode tail;
int size = 0;
@Override
public void add(int index, E element) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index > size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (head == null) {
        head = new DLLNode(element);
        tail = head;
    }
    else if (index == 0) {
        DLLNode temp = new DLLNode(element);
        temp.setNext(head);
        head = temp;
    } else {
        DLLNode temp = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        DLLNode newNode = new DLLNode(element);
        newNode.setNext(temp.getNext());
        newNode.setPrev(temp);
        newNode.getNext().setPrev(newNode);
        temp.setNext(newNode);
    }
    size ++;
}
```

Node class for my DoublyLinkedlist:

```
public class DLLNode<E> {
private DLLNode<E> next;
private DLLNode<E> prev;
private E element;

public DLLNode(E element){
    this.element=element;
    prev=null;
    next=null;
}
public DLLNode(E element, DLLNode prev, DLLNode next) {
    this.element=element;
    this.prev=prev;
    this.next=next;
}
public E getData(){
    return element;
}

public void setData(E element){
    this.element=element;
}

public DLLNode getPrev(){
    return prev;
}

public DLLNode getNext(){
    return next;
}

public void setPrev(DLLNode where){
    prev=where;
}

public void setNext(DLLNode where){
    next=where;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work for three reasons that I can see:

- In the `if (index == 0)` block, you never set the `prev` value of the head node.
- In the `else` block, you never check if you're at the end of the list, so you'll get a `NullPointerException` if you are.
- In both `if (index == 0)` block and `else` block, you don't set `tail` if the new node is the last node.

On a side note: You're using *raw* generics all over. Never use `DLLNode` without a `<` immediately after it. Basically, change all `DLLNode` to `DLLNode<E>`.

---

Here's how you test your own code.

Add this method to `DLLNode`:

```
void verifyIntegrity() {
    if (this.prev != null && this.prev.next != this)
        throw new AssertionError("prev.next is corrupt");
    if (this.next != null && this.next.prev != this)
        throw new AssertionError("next.prev is corrupt");
}
```

Add this method to `DoubleLinkedList`:

```
void verifyIntegrity() {
    int count = 0;
    DLLNode<E> last = this.head;
    for (DLLNode<E> node = this.head; node != null; count++, last = node, node = node.getNext())
        node.verifyIntegrity();
    if (this.tail != last)
        throw new AssertionError("tail is corrupt");
    if (this.size != count)
        throw new AssertionError("size is corrupt");
}
```

Now test you code like this:

```
DoubleLinkedList<Integer> listHead = new DoubleLinkedList<>();
DoubleLinkedList<Integer> listTail = new DoubleLinkedList<>();
DoubleLinkedList<Integer> listMid = new DoubleLinkedList<>();
listHead.verifyIntegrity();
listTail.verifyIntegrity();
listMid.verifyIntegrity();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    listHead.add(0, i);
    listTail.add(i, i);
    listMid.add(i / 2, i);
    listHead.verifyIntegrity();
    listTail.verifyIntegrity();
    listMid.verifyIntegrity();
}
```